# Why does ruby round like this?

Tags: ruby, floating-point, integer

Hi I have the following question:

When I put (1+7/100) in ruby it gives 1.

This is very strange because normally this is how I calculate a 7% increase in Excel.

But when I put (1+7.0/100) it gives me 1.07 which is the correct answer I expected.

Why is ruby doing this? And how do you solve this issue in your calculations in ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This has nothing to do with rounding.**

Ruby does division differently on float than it does on an integer.

If you divide integers, you will always get an integer result.

If you divide with floats (or a mixture of integer and float), you will always get a float result.

---

Remember your order of operations, too. Ruby is going to handle the division before it handles the addition.

`7/100 = 0` so `1+0 = 1`

`7.0/100 = 0.07` so `1+0.07 = 1.07`